# BaseX: Javascript function not working in XSLT

Tags: javascript, xslt, jaxp, basex

I create an XSLT with Altova, now I want to use it with Basex and call the transformation from java. In Altova I don't have any problem, but under Basex I have "[FODC0002] Impossible to compile the stylesheet". A part of the XSLT is:

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:js="urn:custom-javascript" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl js" xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math" extension-element-prefixes="math">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
       <xsl:template match="Linee">
     <root_bordero>
     <xsl:element name="bordero">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Linea"/>
     </xsl:element>
     </root_bordero>
       </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Linea">
    <xsl:variable name="num_corse_mattina" select="count(./Fasce[./@nome='mattina']/orari_partenza/*)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="num_bus" as="xs:integer" select="count(document('/path_to/Autobus.xml')/Autobus/Autobus[./@Linea=current()/@id_linea and ./@Fascia='mattina']/@Targa)"/> 
     .....
    <xsl:variable name="array_bus_mat" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(js:random(number($num_bus),number($num_corse_mattina)),'\s')"/>
    ......
     </xsl:template>
     <msxsl:script language="JavaScript" implements-prefix="js">
           <![CDATA[  
             function random(range,lenght) {

        var array = new Array(lenght);
        var array_key = new Array(lenght);
        var min = 1;
                for (var i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
            array[i]=i+1;
                }
               array_key[0] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (range - min +1))+min;

                for (var i=1; i<lenght; i++) {
                    var key = Math.floor(Math.random() * (range - min +1))+min;

                while(array_key[i-1]==key){
           key = Math.floor(Math.random() * (range - min +1))+min;
                     }
                     array_key[i]=key;
                 }

         var string='';
         for (var i=0; i<lenght-1; i++) {
        string=''+string+array_key[i] + ' '; 
             }
        string=string+array_key[i];

            return string;
                }
            ]]> 
          </msxsl:script>
       </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Under Java, I tried the XSLT transformation using both JAXP and Basex JQX, but the compile error is "The first argument of not static Java function 'random' is not a valid object reference. "

Please, help me!!!

Answer (score 1):

msxsl:script is a proprietary Microsoft extension to the language, you can't expect it to work on non-Microsoft processors.

Comment: Ok, thanks! But what can I use instead?
is it possible to use a javascript function? All examples I found use msxsl:script. Or if it's not, how can I integrate an external java method?

Comment: Every XSLT and XQuery processor has some mechanism for calling out to external code, but it varies by product. You'll need to check the BaseX documentation.